# Bokeh with bokeh_server: updating a plot as it is zoomed

Tags: python, django, plot, bokeh

I have a largeish data set (up to 2.5 million points) that I'd like to downsample for my Bokeh plot and then resample as the user zooms in and out. I'm using bokeh_server with a redis backend.

The server logs now show encouraging 200 HTTP responses, but nothing appears in the browser page. I get the JavaScript error: `Error: Domains other than x not supported yet`. Am I accessing my HDF5 file correctly? How does bokeh know what the dataset is called (it's called `test` in my case).

The relevant bit of my Django view is:

```
def bokeh_test2(request):
    import numpy as np
    import bokeh.plotting as bplot 
    from bokeh.transforms import line_downsample
    import bokeh.embed as embed

    bplot.output_server(docname="downsampling_test")
    source = line_downsample.source(data_url='data/test.hdf5', 
                                 owner_username='defaultuser')
    p = bplot.line('x', 'y', source=source, legend='test')
    bplot.push()
    tag = embed.autoload_server(p, bplot.cursession())

    c = {'bokeh_div': tag}
    return render_to_response('bokeh_test.html', c,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure offhand why this is not working, but I do know that it is not the ideal way to do things. You shouldn't create a new plot every time. You should serve the `autoload_server` tag once, saving a reference to the data source. Then later, update and push just the data source to the Bokeh server, and existing plots in the client will update automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I'm not sure I understand, though. I need a tag for every page served, because different users might select different data sets to visualize. I'll update my question with the latest difficulty, if you'd be able to help.

Comment: Of course, I will help you find an answer. My other comment was about not needing to re-render a whole plot on the zoom, which is what it looked like you were trying to do, but I evidently missed some context.

Comment: Thank you -- if I understand correctly, my view is just injecting the `<script>` tag into my template, and it is this script that interacts with `bokeh-server` running on a different port. So `bplot.push()` should send the data to `bokeh-server` which then responsible for updating the plot seen in the browser... but I'm not seeing a plot and it looks like `bokeh-server` doesn't know how to get at the data it needs from the HDF5 file I specify. I have managed to get the `animated` test working from the Bokeh docs, but this doesn't down-sample or use HDF5.

Comment: Hi, can you come by the Bokeh GH (https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh) and make an issue there? It will be much easier to put you in touch with some of the other devs who know more about this particular feature. This kind of server downsampling is actually in the process of getting some updates and improvements and it would be great to get your feedback, but this is not an ideal place to have that sort of back and forth discussion.

Comment: I'm not confident that I'm experiencing a bug so much as my own lack of knowledge about the Bokeh API, so I've asked my question on the Bokeh mailing list and hope someone can point me in the right direction, Thanks, @bigreddot.